# AssertJ check if JSONArray contains a map with an entry with given key and value

Tags: java, json, unit-testing, testing, assertj

Hi I want to test with `assertThat` if a JSONArray contains an item with a key with a specific value.
For example I have JSONArray:

```
[
  {
    "eventType": "event_1",
    "name": "user_1",
    ....
  },
  {
    "eventType": "event_2",
    "name": "user_2",
    ....
  }
]
```

What I want to test is if this array contains an item with the key: `eventType` with the value: `event_2`
Is it possible to achieve this with `assertThat` without looping through the array and checking each item?

I know it is possible to check if a map contains a given key and value and I also know it is possible to check if an array contains given item. But I didn't found any solution how to combine both things. Someone has an idea how can I combine these two things?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

This is best addressed by https://github.com/lukas-krecan/JsonUnit which will give you much better JSON assertions than the generic AssertJ.

Hope it helps!

Comment: yeah this helped me. Thank you. The solution for my case was `assertThatJson(fullDataMessage).when(IGNORING_EXTRA_FIELDS).isArray().containsAnyOf("{eventType:\"event_2\"}")`

Comment: Glad it helped!